# How to suppress some unsigned-integer-overflow errors from UBsan?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, ubsan

Most of my `-fsanitize=unsigned-integer-overflow` errors are bugs, but sometimes I explicitly use it as intended, which results in UBSan producing false positives.

Is there a way to turn UBSan unsigned-integer-overflow check off for a particular expression?

EDIT in response to Shafik comment, here is an example:

```
unsigned a = 0;
unsigned b = a - 1; // error: unsigned integer overflow
```

Most of the time that is a bug, sometimes it isn't. With UBSan one can find every time that happens, fix the bugs, but I haven't found a way to silence the false positives.

EDIT 2: to enable the check one needs to pass either `-fsanitize=integer` (to enable all integer checks) or `fsanitize=unsigned-integer-overflow`. From the comments below it seems that the check is only available in clang and not in GCC yet.

Comment: Why is it triggered in the first place? Overflow in unsigned arithmetic is well-defined.

Comment: @black UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer has a check that allows you to find unsigned integer overflow. It is not undefined behavior, but at least in my programs it is typically a bug (not always, and hence the question). I would like to have a way of expressing "here I am explicitly using wraparound behavior".

Comment: You mean **`-fsanitize=integer`**, that triggers a runtime error _not_ UB.

Comment: @black yes, sorry, integer.

Comment: And GCC doesn't have it. (yet, apparently)

Comment: I use `-fsanitize=address,integer,undefined` to get the error, and to disable the check that is at fault I can use `-fno-sanitize=unsigned-integer-overflow`.

Comment: As I read the docs, the parameter appears to be `-fsanitize=unsigned-integer-overflow`.

Comment: @MarkB that flag should be enough to trigger the error. Thanks.

Comment: Removing comment since they don't have much anymore

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to wrap the operation in a function you can use `__attribute__((no_sanitize("integer")))` like so (*[see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/AjzimH2LjwsPy4P8)*):

```
__attribute__((no_sanitize("integer")))
unsigned calc( unsigned a )
{
    return a - 1 ;
}
```

I found this via a bug report/feature request [Suppression support for UbSAN](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=19834).

The clang [documentation on attributes](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html) does not indicate any way to apply this except to a function:

> Use the no_sanitize attribute on a function declaration to specify that a particular instrumentation or set of instrumentations should not be applied to that function. The attribute takes a list of string literals, which have the same meaning as values accepted by the -fno-sanitize= flag. For example, **attribute**((no_sanitize("address", "thread"))) specifies that AddressSanitizer and ThreadSanitizer should not be applied to the function.

Comment: Thanks! I'm marking this as the answer. Do you happen to know if one can apply this attribute to an expression?

Comment: @gnzlbg it appears not from the linked bug report, it was closed since the form I gave in my example worked for the reporter but you may want to see if it can be reopened since a way to apply it to statements would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Using the bitwise NOT operator seems to fix the alleged runtime error.

```
auto b = ~a;
auto c = ~a - 5;
```

Comment: Actually it just avoids the overflow but only in this very special case.