# How to terminate clang-instrumented program when clang-sanitizer finds an error?

Tags: c++, clang, clang++

Say I have the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

float foo(float f)
    { return (f / 0); }

int main(void) {
    foo(1.0f);
    std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
}
```

If I invoke `clang++ -fsanitize=undefined main.cpp && ./a.out` then it will output:

```
main.cpp:4:32: runtime error: division by zero
hello
```

Is there a way to terminate `a.out` as soon as an error is detected? I.e. in such a way that it displays:

```
main.cpp:4:32: runtime error: division by zero
```

without displaying `hello` on the following line? (because it will have terminated before)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30809022/420683 --> you can use the environment variable `UBSAN_OPTIONS=halt_on_error=1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [`-fno-sanitize-recover`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html#usage) command line argument:

```
clang++ -fsanitize=undefined -fno-sanitize-recover=undefined main.cpp
```